# Show/Hide children in menu when clicking on parent (with pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have bare basic knowledge in JavaScript, and I'm trying to create a menu where :

- Only the first level parents are visible.
- Then when you click on them, their children will be displayed.
- If you click on them again (or maybe click anywhere on the page) they will close
- Must work for 2 level children (for example children of children)

This is what I have so far, and I know this is far from being right. I found a bunch of jQuery solutions online, but I want it pure JavaScript & CSS.

*Note: I also need to keep the number of classes & id's used to a minimum as I want to be able to use this with the WordPress menu structure. But if I need to manually add a "parent" class to each parent that has children, then that will be fine.*

My JavaScript :

```js
var menuParents = document.querySelectorAll("#my-menu .parent");
menuParents.forEach(menuParent => {
   document.querySelector("#my-menu .parent").addEventListener("click", ToggleMenu);
      function ToggleMenu() {
         document.querySelector("#my-menu .parent ul").style.display = 'block';
      }
});
```

My CSS :

```css
#my-menu .parent ul {display: none;}
```

And, finally, my HTML :

```html
<ul id="my-menu">
   <li>Standard Item</li>
   <li>Standard Item</li>
   <li class="parent">Item with children
      <ul>
         <li>child item</li>
         <li>child item</li>
         <li class="parent">child item with children
           <li>second level child</li>
           <li>second level child</li>
         </li>
         <li>child item</li>
         <li>child item</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Standard Item</li>
   <li>Standard Item</li>
   <li class="parent">Item with children
      <ul>
        <li>child item</li>
        <li>child item</li>
        <li class="parent">child item with children
           <li>second level child</li>
           <li>second level child</li>
        </li>
        <li>child item</li>
        <li>child item</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Standard Item</li>
   <li>Standard Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the specific element in the `forEach`, and then just get the `firstElementChild` of it, and toggle the `display` style:

```js
const toggle = {
    block: 'none',
    none: 'block'
}

function ToggleMenu(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.target.classList.toggle('active');
    event.target.firstElementChild.style.display = toggle[event.target.firstElementChild.style.display] || 'block';
}
var menuParents = document.querySelectorAll("#my-menu .parent");
menuParents.forEach(menuParent => {
    menuParent.addEventListener("click", ToggleMenu);
})
```

```css
#my-menu .parent ul {display: none;}
.active {
    color: red
}

.active > * {
    color: black
}
```

```html
<ul id="my-menu">
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li class="parent">Item with children
        <ul>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li class="parent">child item with children
              <ul>
                <li>second level child</li>
                <li>second level child</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li class="parent">Item with children
        <ul>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li class="parent">child item with children
              <ul>
                <li>second level child</li>
                <li>second level child</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
</ul>
```

or without "parent" class

```js
const toggle = {
    block: 'none',
    none: 'block'
}

function ToggleMenu(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (event.target.firstElementChild) {
      event.target.classList.toggle('active');
      event.target.firstElementChild.style.display = toggle[event.target.firstElementChild.style.display] || 'block';
    }
}
var menuParents = document.querySelectorAll("#my-menu li > ul");
menuParents.forEach(menuParent => {
    menuParent.parentElement.addEventListener("click", ToggleMenu);
})
```

```css
#my-menu li > ul {display: none;}
.active {
    color: red
}

.active > * {
    color: black
}
```

```html
<ul id="my-menu">
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Item with children
        <ul>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item with children
              <ul>
                <li>second level child</li>
                <li>second level child</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Item with children
        <ul>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item with children
              <ul>
                <li>second level child</li>
                <li>second level child</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How would I do the second level children?

Comment: just fixed it, try now

Comment: Good use of ```stopPropagation```, but the toggle to keep track of elements is kind of unnecessary. Elements keep track of their style anyway, so you can just use that to determine whether or not the clicked on element should be hidden or not.

Comment: @TARN4T1ON it's not keeping track of the element, it's just convenience for getting the next style, if I plug in 'block' I get 'none', if I plug in 'none' I get 'block'.

Comment: @dave thank you so much, it works great. Once last thing: Is it possible to add an "active" class once the parent is clicked? It will only be used for me to style an open parent with css. I tried editing your code just now by adding "classList.add("active")" to the function but it didn't work

Comment: @dave Oh, yeah, my mistake. Didn't take a proper look.

Comment: @Shtarley added the active class, and some css so you can see it working

Comment: @dave Thank you so, so, so much. You just made my entire day so much easier. You are awesome.

Comment: @Shtarley just saw you might not want the "parent" class, so showed how you can make it work without it

Comment: @dave Thank you, that is brilliant! Much nicer solution. The only thing I like more about the previous version is that the active class only gets applied to parents that actually have children. I want to use the active class to add an arrow, so I don't want that arrow to appear if there is no children. But I assume if you don't use a parent class, then it is really difficult not to apply the active class to everything. Is there an easy solution to limit the active class when not using the parent class?
By the way... the "active" class issue seems to only be on level 2 children.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is slightly wrong: your parents inside parents don't have `ul` elements.

```
<ul id="my-menu">
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li class="parent">Item with children
        <ul>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li class="parent">child item with children
                <!-- here -->
                <ul>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>child item</li>
    <li>child item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li class="parent">Item with children
        <ul>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li class="parent">child item with children
                <!-- and here -->
                <ul>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>child item</li>
    <li>child item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript wise, your toggle function doesn't actually toggle anything, or it won't toggle more than once, anyway.

Another problem is that the click handler will also get called when you click on a parent of a parent, which this code accounts for too.

Here I used an anonymous function. You don't have to do this, a named function would work just fine, but it doesn't clutter your only namespace.

This will also work with any level of parents: the attached snippet has second level parents.

```
var menuParents = document.querySelectorAll("#my-menu .parent");
menuParents.forEach(
    menuParent => {
        menuParent.addEventListener(
            "click",
            // inline, anonymous function
            //  also accepts an event parameter
            function (event) {
                // check if the parent element was actually clicked (prevent parent of parent from toggling display)
                if (event.target == this) {
                    // this == menuParent
                    // select ul from menuParent
                    var menuChild = this.querySelector("ul");

                    // toggle child menu display, based on it's current display
                    if (menuChild.style.display == "block") {
                        // here, you could also set the display to null, since your CSS sets the display to none anyway
                        menuChild.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        menuChild.style.display = "block";
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Tested on Chrome 87.0.4280.88.

```js
var menuParents = document.querySelectorAll("#my-menu .parent");
menuParents.forEach(
    menuParent => {
        menuParent.addEventListener(
            "click",
            // inline, anonymous function
            //  also accepts an event parameter
            function (event) {
                if (event.target == this) {
                    // this == menuParent
                    // select ul from menuParent
                    var menuChild = this.querySelector("ul");

                    // toggle child menu display, based on it's current display
                    if (menuChild.style.display == "block") {
                        // here, you could also set the display to null, since your CSS sets the display to none anyway
                        menuChild.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        menuChild.style.display = "block";
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

```css
#my-menu .parent ul {
    padding-left: 16px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="my-menu">
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li class="parent">Item with children
        <ul>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li class="parent">child item with children
                <ul>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                    <li class="parent">second level parent
                    <ul>
                        <li>third level child</li>
                        <li>third level child</li>
                    </ul>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li class="parent">Item with children
        <ul>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li class="parent">child item with children
                <ul>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                    <li class="parent">second level parent
                    <ul>
                        <li>third level child</li>
                        <li>third level child</li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                    <li>second level child</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>child item</li>
            <li>child item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
    <li>Standard Item</li>
</ul>
```